# SelectList (DropDown) estático usando ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

Necesito hacer este `select`:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>ESPOSO(A)</option>
    <option>HIJO(A)</option>
    <option>CONYUGUE</option>
    <option>ACUDIENTE</option>
</select>
```

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo en Razor, estuve mirando unas publicaciones y artículos pero solo muestra como cargarlos dinámicamente con datos de la base de datos, y yo solo necesito esos datos estáticos, pero no doy cómo.

Mi `Controller`:

```
// GET: Families/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
```

Mi `View`:

```
@model OldMutual.Models.Families

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Families</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.documento_identidad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.documento_identidad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.documento_identidad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parentesco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parentesco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parentesco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.names, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.names, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.names, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fecha_nacimiento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fecha_nacimiento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fecha_nacimiento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.sexo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.sexo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.sexo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.celular, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.celular, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.celular, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.codigo_colaborador, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.codigo_colaborador, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.codigo_colaborador, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Cabe aclarar que el `select` es para el `model.parentesco`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parentesco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parentesco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.parentesco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente para agregar datos al modelo en el controlador `Create` ya los valores de dropdown dependen de la misma pero esa es la idea yo por ejemplo puse este modelo

```
public class Parentesco
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Controlador

```html
public ActionResult Create()
{
            List<Parentesco> Parentescos = new List<Parentesco>();
            Parentesco parentesco1 = new Parentesco();
            parentesco1.Text = "ESPOSO(A)";
            parentesco1.Value = "ESPOSO(A)";
            Parentescos.Add(parentesco1);
            Parentesco parentesco2 = new Parentesco();
            parentesco2.Text = "HIJO(A)";
            parentesco2.Value = "HIJO(A)";
            Parentescos.Add(parentesco2);
            Parentesco parentesco3 = new Parentesco();
            parentesco3.Text = "CONYUGUE";
            parentesco3.Value = "CONYUGUE";
            Parentescos.Add(parentesco3);
            ViewBag.Parentescos= new SelectList(Parentescos, "Text", "Value");
            return View();
}
```

vista

```html
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Parentescos, ViewBag.Parentescos as SelectList , "Seleccione uno", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: una consulta, si quiero crear otro select list, como hago?? tambien en el create, intente copiar y pegar el codigo cambiar los valores pero me da error

Comment: Muchas gracias, se me habia oldidado crear la funcion

Comment: Cada vez que vaya a crear un Dropdown List tengo que crear una public class Parentesco??

Answer (score 2):

Primero, tenemos que crear el modelo asociado a parentescos:

```
public class Parentescos
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentescoId { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

Luego, crear una lista estática del tipo de parentescos, y almacenar en el `ViewBag` generando el Html dinámico:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Parentescos> parentesco = new List<Parentescos>() {
        new Parentescos(){ ParentescoId = 1, Descripcion = "ESPOSO(A)" },
        new Parentescos(){ ParentescoId = 2, Descripcion = "HIJO(A)" },
        new Parentescos(){ ParentescoId = 3, Descripcion = "CONYUGUE" },
        new Parentescos(){ ParentescoId = 4, Descripcion = "ACUDIENTE" }};

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var type in parentesco)
    {
        sb.Append("<option value='" + type.ParentescoId + "'>" + type.Descripcion + "</option>");
    }

    ViewBag.parentesco = sb.ToString();

    return View();
}
```

Del lado de la vista solo hacemos el render del Html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ParentescoId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select class="form-control" name="ParentescoId">
            @Html.Raw(ViewBag.parentesco)
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```