# ¿Como enviar un conjunto de datos de tipo IList<> del Controlador a la Vista?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

obtengo una cantidad N de elementos de la sessio, ¿como puedo enviarlo a la vista y mostrarlo en un DropdownList?

o como en en windowsForm se lo conoce como combobox

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IList<CModel> c = (IList<CModel>)Session["CSeleccionado"];
        ViewBag.C = new SelectList(co, "IdC", "Descripcion");  
        return View();
    }
```

mi vista ya esta enlazada con

```
@model S.Controllers.R.Param
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

quiero mostrarla en la misma vista

Comment: todo funciona a la prefeccion, en la vista es en la que me falta trabajar, help me!!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [SelectList (DropDown) estático usando ASP.Net MVC 5](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60522/selectlist-dropdown-est%c3%a1tico-usando-asp-net-mvc-5)

Comment: no, revise ese codigo y no es similar al mio, yo estoy atrapando los registros de mi base de datos en que las almaceno en el objeto `c` que luego los convierto en IList<> ,son como 35 registros,

Comment: en otras palabras, no es estatica, es dinamica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, quieres mostrar la lista de CModel que tienes como opciones en tu drop down. Para lograr eso es necesario le pases tu lista que tienes contenida en tu ViewBag como el segundo parámetro del helper DropDownList.

Algo así como esto:

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdC", ViewBag.C as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

ó, para mostrar un valor nulo de 'Select an option'

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdC", ViewBag.C as SelectList, "Select an option", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta fue mi solución.

```
 @Html.DropDownList("IdC", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

espero les sirva

Comment: Veo que en la pregunta pones la lista en la variable `ViewBag.C`, pero aquí en la respuesta solo pones la definición del DropDownList, ¿cómo es que se llena esa lista desplegable en el View?

Comment: utilice el como ejemplo un combobox para que me entendieran.